# Fill @Html.Hidden with div value

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a div like this:

```
<div id ="carmodel"></div>
```

This div gets populated using Javascript 5 seconds after pageload, so it will look like this:

```
<div id ="carmodel">Audi A4</div>
```

Now I need to send the text inside the "Carmodel" div to the controller when a form is submitted.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller"))
{
     @Html.TextBox("textbox1", "")
     @Html.TextBox("textbox2", "")   
     <input type="submit" value="Subtmit"/>
}
```

I thought about using a hidden field and posting it together, but I don't know how to populate the hidden field with the text in "Carmodel" div:

```
@Html.Hidden("carmodelhiden", "");
```

It seems as if I need to use JQuery to retrieve the text like this:

```
var value = $("#carmodel").text();
```

But how do I then send this to the controller?

I also thought about using .ajax to post it but not sure how to handle the value in the controller once it's there, since the ajax method in the controller would be separate from where the form gets posted.

Anybody have any advice?

Comment: Just putting the java script in the script tag wont work. You need to hook into an event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the value of the hidden input:

```
$('#carModelHidden').val(...);
```

Comment: doh! I didn't think about that! let me try it :)

Comment: BTW, why didn't you? Your question is basically asking how to set the value of the hidden input.

Comment: What value are you passing? Use the Javascript debugger and network tools.

Comment: What do you see in the DOM inspector? In particular, does it have an ID?

Comment: Also, I would use html.HiddenFor(m => // some property in model) with a strongly typed view. Also make sure its between your form using statement.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put the hidden value between the form using statement. Also, use a strongly typed view to bind with a property in your model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller"))
{
<div id ="carmodel">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SomeProperty)
</div>
}




@section scripts{
<script>
// Hook into some event and set: 
$('#carModelHidden').val(...);
</script>
}
```

Comment: It is good practice...How else are you going to pass the value to your controller? Viewbag?

Comment: The answer is still good, the binding was only a suggestion...Just use @html.Hidden instead of HidenFor if binding is not an option for you.